# Можно ли удаленно обновлять дизайн лайотов?

Tags: android, kotlin

Возможно ли удаленно менять дизайн layout'a или вообще подгружать верстку с сервера?
Может уже кто-то создавал такую тему, но я порывшись в интернете ничего не нашел)

Comment: Давно интересовался. Вариант использовать WebView и, либо, подгружать веб страницу, либо скачать шаблон с сервера и отображать локально.

Comment: этот вариант мне не нравится, но я его знал. Я хочу чтобы именно XML был)
Пример тому может быть ВКонтакте. Много раз замечал, что дизайн менялся без обновления самого приложения.

Comment: Теоретически можно придумать свой формат и создавать разметку програмно.

Comment: Не знаюm насколько это поможет но посмотрите на Firebase Remote Config)

Comment: Firebase remote config это немного другое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, но воспользоваться встроенным механизмом inflate не получится, все view  придется создавать вручную. В качестве готовой реализации можно взять [DivKit](https://divkit.tech/) от Яндекса.

Если готовые решения не подходят, то можно все сделать самому. Все подклассы `View` можно создать в рантайме используя [один из конструкторов](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#public-constructors_1). Лучше использовать конструктор принимающий только `Context`, но если он не доступен, то можно передать `null`/`0` в качестве остальных аргументов. После этого надо будет добавить созданные view в иерархию экрана используя [`addView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)).

---

Встроенным inflate нельзя воспользоваться [по довольно интересной причине](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup)): aapt делает предпроцессинг xml-файлов и в apk попадают уже обработанные бинарные версии исходных файлов. `LayoutInflater` умеет работать только с такими бинарными данными и подать ему обычный xml-файл нельзя.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. все понятно.